# Liquid filter same of item?

Tags: sorting, jekyll, liquid

I'm new to Jekyll and Liquid, and I've been trying to utilize a site that has 100+ pages, separated into 15 modules. I need the navigation to reflect only to related pages, but I'm stuck on how to do this efficiently. For example, a directory like:

```
animal-species/
├── _docs/
│   ├── mammals/
│   │  ├── mam-page01.md
│   │  └── mam-page02.md
│   ├── reptiles/
│   │  ├── rep-page01.md
│   │  └── rep-page02.md
```

Set in pages:

```
title: Mammals Overview
module: mammals
---
```

docs.yml:

```
- module: mammals
    title: Section Title
    docs:
     - mam-page01
     - mam-page02
- module: reptiles
    title: Section Title
    docs:
     - rep-page01
     - rep-page02
```

In my nav.html file I've tried sorting with `{% for section in site.data.docs | where page.module == page.module %}` or `page.module == section.module` with no luck. I've also tried creating nested collections with 3.7.0 and `collections_dir:`, also failing. Every page is available to each other in all navs:

navigation of site
[image]

How can I set the nav to only show same-module pages? I have 15 modules and with like some sort of global sorting without having to code for all sub-directories.

Thank you for your help/patience! I'm very green to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've bypassed a collections directory and `_config.yml` restructure but adding additional variables to by assign output:

```
{% assign docs = site.data.docs[page.module] | map: 'docs' | join: ',' | split: ',' %}

{% for document in docs %}
  {% assign dir = page.module | prepend: "/" | append: "/" %}
  {% assign document_url = document | prepend: {{dir}} | append:"/" %}
  {% if document_url == page.url %}
```

"Previous"/"Next" buttons will only link to items with the same module. A simple solution that took me forever to divine.